# Are the US drone strikes inside Pakistan approved by the Pakistani government?

Tags: united-states, pakistan

Are the drone strikes by the USA (from the early 2000's until to date) inside Pakistani border approved by the Pakistani government (e.g. by any secret agreement), or, is the USA doing it unilaterally?

If those drone strikes were not approved by the Pakistani government, why didn't Pakistan take any measure against them (e.g. SAM missile strike on drones, and so on) if the USA never paid heed to them?

Comment: Not many countries possess the industrial power and knowledge to produce cheap weaponry against drones.

Comment: @mootmoot, FYI Pakistan has eleven Spada 2000 Aspide batteries. Their latest inclusion is Chinese LY-80 .

Comment: Do you know how large a drone view on radar screen and missile tracking system?

Comment: "by any secret agreemen" - the problem is that any such agreement is... well, ***secret***. No poster here would know about it (or if they happen to know, disclose it). Moreover, some of such "agreements" are unwritten tacit wink wink nod nod understandings rather then anything formal.

Answer (score 3):

At least in 2013 there was serious government protest.

https://www.voanews.com/a/us-accused-of-unlawful-killings-pakistan-drone-strikes/1774276.html

https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/pakistani-court-declares-us-drone-strikes-in-the-countrys-tribal-belt-illegal-8609843.html

Why Pakistan hasn't taken military action to stop them is less clear to me.

Comment: My guess is some, they are fine with (and approved), some were approved but they claim not and publicly complain about for political reasons, some they don't approve about or don't know about, and take issue with.  Why no action on the last category?  USA sends a good amount of military assistance, and hasn't formally shown any favoritism towards India in their ongoing disputes and general relations.

Comment: Indeed those are very similar to my guesses, along with the possibility of it being a military problem Pakistan is perhaps un-ready to reliably deal with across a large area they are not particularly in control of. But they are guesses, and I'm not well versed in Pakistan's internal politics or the state of the art military.